# ValueError when iterating through simple list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying (as a newb Pythoneer) to translate an old homework assignment from Java to Python. I am getting a TypeError when I try to iterate through a list. It is claiming that I am not using an integer value for my index, but I can't see how I am not. I've probably included too much code, but just in case the error isn't where I think it is (**TypeError is on very last line**):

```
def power(x, y):
    if isinstance(y, int):
        solution = x
        if y == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            for i in range(1,y):
                solution = solution*x
        return solution
    else:
        raise TypeError("Power: Non-Integer power argument")

def factorial(x):
    if isinstance(x, int) and x >= 0:
        if x == 1 or x == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            solution = int(x)
            while x > 1:
                solution = solution*(x-1)
                x -= 1
            return solution
    else:
        raise TypeError("Factorial: argument must be a positive integer")

def abs(x):
    if x < 0:
        x = -x
    return x


# Calculates the coefficients of the
# Taylor series of Sin(x).
# center argument must be 0, pi/4, pi, or 3pi/2
def coef_calc(center):
    coef = [1]*32
    i = int(0)
    c_temp = 1  # temporary holding place for calculated coefficient

    if center in [0, PI/4, PI, 3*PI/2]:

        # Mclauren Series (center = 0)
        if center == 0:
            while c_temp > 1.0e-31:
                c_temp = power(-1, i)/factorial(2*i + 1)
                coef[i] = c_temp
                i += 1
    else:
        raise ValueError("Argument not in [0, pi/4, pi, 3pi/2]")

    return coef


# CONSTANTS
PI = 3.1415926535897932
SQRT_TWO = 1.41421356237309504880

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(power(4,2))
    print(factorial(4))
    print(abs(-0))

    coef = coef_calc(0)
    for x in coef:
        print(coef[x] + "\n")
```

Comment: which line are you getting the `valueerror`

Comment: @Jai will add that in. It's the very last line.

Comment: Strange, when I run this code I get a TypeError, not a ValueError. What's your error message? Mine is `list indices must be integers or slices, not float`

Comment: `x` is a member of `coef`, not an index into it. You just want `print(x, "\n")`

Comment: @Kevin I mis-spoke, the error you see is what I got. Will edit... again.

Comment: @glibdud makes sense. Now it doesn't like the fact that I'm using the "+" operator with a string and a float. I should use a comma, or something? I'll slink back to tutorials.

Comment: Yeah, you have options. Use a comma, use a formatted string (`print("{}\n".format(x))`), use an empty print for the extra line feed (`print(x); print()`), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `for x in coef:`, `x` is the item iterating through `coef` and not its index, so when you do `coef[x]` it's expecting `x` to be an index of `coef`, which causes the error.  If you want to get both the index and item, use `for i, x in enumerate(coef):` where `i` is the index and `x` is the item.

Your code is simple to fix though.  Just change the last line to this instead:

```
print(x)
```

You don't need the "\n" since each print statement be a new line.

Answer (score 0):

- I ran your code the variable `coef` has float values in it
- What I would do is the follwing:

  ```
  for i in range(len(coef)):
      print(coef[i],"\n")
  ```
- This way access the list by index and not by value
- If you want to access it by value :

  ```
  for i in range(len(coef)):
      print(i,"\n")
  ```

Comment: That would just give you `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

Comment: dude I did a typo over there... try it now..,. I just edited my answer.... I ran it no error now

Comment: Ok, that works better. But isn't it kind of roundabout to iterate through the indices of a list just to access the elements of the list by index? Why not just do `for x in in coef: print(x, "\n")`?

Comment: yes you can do that `for x in coef: print(x, "\n")`... but i thought you wanted to access it by index

Comment: _"i thought you wanted to access it by index"_. If by "you", you mean me specifically: nope, I prefer to iterate directly over values when possible. If by "you", you mean the OP: not as I interpret the question, but who knows how he really feels. If by "you", you mean the general community interested in idiomatic style: they, too, prefer to iterate directly over values when possible

Comment: Depends on the programmer what he prefers